# removing duplication in csv file column

Tags: php, csv, duplicates

i have a csv file that gets a data of cars spare parts and it has acoulmn for company , car name and model and the column of car name has duplication , i tried to use a functions to remove it but it removes  all the row not the duplicated data in the coulmn.
this is my function

```
    public function import(){
    $this->load->language('sale/orders');
    $json = array();
    $filename =  explode ('.xlsx',$this->request->post['filename']);
    $fullpath = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $this->request->post['filename']; //$filename[0] . ".xlsx";
    $json['full'] = $fullpath;        

        $file = "your-file.xls";
        $handle = fopen($fullpath, "r");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "custom_orders_options`");
        $c = 0;                 
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
        //$filesop = array_map("utf8_encode", $filesop); //added
        //$filesop = iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $filesop );
        $company = $filesop[0];            
        $company_ar = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($filesop[1], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $filesop[1]);            
        $car_name = $filesop[2];
        $car_name_ar = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($filesop[3], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $filesop[3]);
        $model = $filesop[4];
        $model_ar = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($filesop[5], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $filesop[5]);


        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "custom_orders_options` (company,car_name,model,company_ar,car_name_ar,model_ar) VALUES ('$company','$car_name','$model','$company_ar','$car_name_ar','$model_ar')");

        $c = $c + 1;            
        }

        if($query){
        $json['status'] = $this->language->get('success_import') .': '. $c;            
        }else{
        $json['status'] = $this->language->get('error_import');      
        }
    //var_dump($query);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

it works fine for company but car name show many duplication data so can any one help ?

Comment: You need to post example input and expected output.

Comment: oki this is the site http://www.arbapart.com/index.php?route=custom/order and the problem is in Car name there is aduplication in data i want car , you can use these data for login directly:

Comment: oki this is the site http://www.arbapart.com/index.php?route=custom/order and the problem is in Car name there is aduplication in data i want car , you can use these data for login directly: email:phenomena4ever@gmail.com and password:123456 ,thanks for your interest